# Android Studio: How to see source for FirebasebaseInstanceId

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was trying to check on implementation of few methods inside firebaseInstanceId class but I was routed to generated stub file instead.

```
public class FirebaseInstanceId {
    private static java.util.Map<java.lang.String,com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId> zzbhH;
    private static com.google.firebase.iid.zze zzclh;
    private final com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp zzcli;
    private final com.google.firebase.iid.zzd zzclj;
    private final java.lang.String zzclk;

    public static com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId getInstance() { /* compiled code */ }

    @android.support.annotation.Keep
    public static synchronized com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId getInstance(@android.support.annotation.NonNull com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp firebaseApp) { /* compiled code */ }

    private FirebaseInstanceId(com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp firebaseApp, com.google.firebase.iid.zzd zzd) { /* compiled code */ }

    java.lang.String zzabM() { /* compiled code */ }

    public java.lang.String getId() { /* compiled code */ }

    public long getCreationTime() { /* compiled code */ }
```

Comment: Play Services are **not** open source, thus you cannot see deobfuscated sources.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable **Java Bytecode Decompiler** from Android studio.

**To enable decompiler follow below step**

- Press shift 2 times. the popup will appear then search for **Java Bytecode Decompiler**. just like below image.

[image]

Bingo now you can check stub code!!

[image]

If you have not downloaded source code for SDK tools then you can download it from SDK manager in Android studio.

[image]

Comment: i was not able to find official source for firebase. that's where i couldn't get my byte code decomplied :-( . where can i get official source code ?

Comment: You can find inside SDK. please check my updated answer.